# Text exits the div

Tags: css, wordpress, text

I would need a hand to understand how to solve the following error that keeps coming out of this page: https://www.stylehaus.it/magazine-2/

the text that should be contained in the div comes out and doesn't stop, how can I solve?

I tried putting "word-wrap: break-word;" in the css in all points but nothing changes...

thank you very much[image]

Comment: try white-space: break-spaces;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing

```
.asrafp-filter-result {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

or use

```
.am_cont {
    white-space: normal;
}
```